# inserir valor de outro formulario automaticamente no textbox ativo

Tags: vba

venho novamente até vós pedir uma ajuda. essa ao meu ver é do nivel hard.
tenho dois formularios
o primeiro tem cinco textbox
o segundo é um numpad com os botões do zero a nove, a virgula , o enter e um textbox que serve de visor onde posso ver os valores enquanto vou digitando.
se no primeiro formulario eu clico no textbox1 ele vai ativar o formulario numpad. onde vou digitar o valor. ao dar enter ou fechar o numpad preciso que o valor seja inserido no textbox1.
se no primeiro formulario eu clico no textbox2 ele vai ativar o formulario numpad. onde vou digitar o valor. ao dar enter ou fechar o numpad preciso que o valor seja inserido no textbox2.
resumindo preciso encontrar uma maneira do formulario 2 saber qual textbox eu cliquei para inserir o valor ai.
qualquer ajuda é bem vinda...
gracias

Answer (score 0):

Há várias maneiras de comunicar entre dois formulários, uma maneira simples de verificar isto é realizando o seguinte.

## Exemplo

Dois formulários são criados, o `Userform1` e o `Userform2`

[image: Árvore de Projeto]

#### Userform1

O primeiro formulário possui duas caixas de texto de nome `TextBox1` e `TextBox2`.

[image: Formulário 1]

#### Userform2

O segundo possui um botão `CommandButton1` e uma caixa de texto `TextBox1`

[image: Formulário 2]

## Código

#### Variável Global

Portanto, uma variável global de nome `chamador` pode ser adicionada num Módulo. No caso do exemplo inserir o código abaixo no Módulo 1:

```
Public chamador As String
```

#### Userform1

O código do primeiro formulário irá mostrar o segundo formulário e atribuir o valor do nome da caixa de texto à variável `chamador`, isto acontecerá quando o evento de apertar Enter for acionado.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    UserForm2.Show
    chamador = "TextBox1"
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox2_Enter()
    UserForm2.Show
    chamador = "TextBox2"
End Sub
```

#### Userform2

Ao inicializar o segundo formulário, o valor da textbox que mostrou o formulário, será mostrado na caixa de texto `TextBox1`

E ao clicar no botão, o valor escrito em `Userform2.TextBox1` será escrito na caixa de texto que mostrou o segundo formulário.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm1.Controls(chamador) = Me.TextBox1
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.TextBox1 = chamador
End Sub
```

> Para outras maneiras [refira a esta resposta do
>   SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32520874/7690982). Respondida pelo
>   [Siddharth
>   Rout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout)